# Input file(jpg/png) uploading and showing are not working in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

File Button is not showing the jpeg image after uploading in locally

Below is the code i have written in react js...

```
categoryImageArray = [];
getCategoryImageLink = (e) => {
    let files = e.target.files;
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    reader.onload = (e) => {
       categoryImageArray.push(e.target.result); 
    }
}
```

and below is the JSX code

```
**IMG SRC**


<div>
<img src = { "'" + categoryImageArray[0] + "'" } />
</div>
```

**Input File**

```
<input type="file" onChange = { this.getCategoryImageLink } />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use state for this,set the value of categoryImageArray in state and change it's value in getCategoryImageLink function
Try this.

```
getCategoryImageLink = (e) => {
    let files = e.target.files;
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    reader.onload = (e) => {
       this.setState({categoryImageArray: ...this.state.categoryImageArray,e.target.result}); 
    }
}
```